# Pi prompts for SSH passphrase

Tags: networking, ssh, putty

I have just set up SSH key pairs for logging into my Pi remotely from my windows box with Putty in my home network.

It does not prompt for a password (as I have set that to "no" in sshd_config).

But when I login with putty, it prompts me for the passphrase for the RSA key everytime.

How do turn off the passphrase prompt?  I just want to login without entering any passphrase, and have it based on private/public key creds alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I seem to have a found a solution, but I'm not sure if there is a better way.

I have Pageant (Putty authentication agent) running and I ensured my private key has been added.

Putty now authenticates automatically.

Comment: Great solution - another way is to save the private key without password protection, but that is not very secure at all.. :-)

Comment: +1 I'm not a Putty or Windows user, but for posterity, the equivalent of Pageant if you are using `ssh` from, e.g., a linux terminal or X session, is `ssh-agent` -- you register a key with it and enter the password once, thereafter you don't need to enter a password every time you use SSH.